# What is the correct translation for "For posterity"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

The context is: A personal family motto that means that whatever is done, the family would always do things for the future family members who are not yet born. Like what Tywin Lannister said to Jamie; The family name is what remains(paraphrased).

Google translate translated it to 'in posterum'. I have heard people here say Translate is not always accurate.

Answer (score 1):

*Ad perpetuam rei memoriam* is a bit of boilerplate that can be found at the beginning of many papal documents. It is commonly translated as "for posterity" in English.

As one example, see [here](https://www.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/la/apost_constitutions/documents/hf_jp-ii_apc_25011983_divinus-perfectionis-magister.html) (Latin) and [here](https://www.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/en/apost_constitutions/documents/hf_jp-ii_apc_25011983_divinus-perfectionis-magister.html) (English).

Comment: Doesn't really align with the usage OP is asking for though, does it? It does translate as "for posterity" but literally it's something like "for the everlasting memory of this (the subject being written about)". Nothing about safeguarding the descendants, just "don't forget".